# What are the differences between command options and switches?

Tags: options

From Java in a Nutshell:

> The syntax of the  jar  command is intentionally very similar to that
>   of the Unix  tar command. This similarity is the reason why  jar  uses
>   **command options**, rather than
>   **switches** (as the other Java platform commands do).

I was wondering what the differences are between command options and switches? I have understood that they mean the same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of `jar`’s options, the distinction is that `jar` follows `tar`’s traditional syntax, rather than the hyphen-prefixed syntax used in other tools. Apart from `-C` and `-J`, `jar`’s options are all single letters, with no “switch character” (`-` in Unix style). Other Java commands such as `jmap` use `-` to introduce *all* their options, and option names are often longer than a single letter.

In general, you’re right, options and switches are the same. (Some might consider that switches refer specifically to on/off options, I don’t think there’s a general rule.)